# Tiberius UTF-8 error using rust and cyrillic characters

Tags: mysql, rust

I'm trying to query a MySQL database using Tiberius. Here is code sample

```
    let rows = client
      .simple_query("select * from some_table")
      .await?
      .into_results()
      .await?;
```

I get the error: `Error: UTF-8 error`
When I query column with numbers only it works well, but with Cyrillic text it doesn't.

The database has next collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

Comment: Rust strings are UTF-8, Latin1 is not a valid subset of UTF-8. You are going to need to use something like https://crates.io/crates/encoding_rs to decode latin1 strings.

Comment: Got it. Could you provide more information how to use this crate with tiberius please?